# Why was this Q&A closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen

I posted this Q&A style question: [How do I solve this projectile motion problem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/783653/). The reason for posting this is because I know that there are a large number of questions regarding how to approach projectile motion problems. I also know that college and AP courses are covering this content now, which is likely related to this upsurge.

In answering these questions, I would like a resource in the form of a stack exchange question to reference. I think the framework I provided in the answer is solid and answers a very relevant question in a way that I did not see on the site previously. I answered the question myself, and I intend to accept that answer since that is what the Q&A was made for. Despite this being the (in my opinion obvious) goal, the question was closed. I do not understand what the point of this is, and I think the question should be reopened.

Why must this question stay closed?

Comment: *Why must this question stay closed?* It’s open now.

Comment: Thanks to this meta post ;) @Ghoster

Comment: Yes, I realize that.

Comment: I think it helps if you add a disclaimer to the *question* making it clear this is meant as a  reference question. (This does not prevent people from not noting it, but it decreases the chance; at least one would hope so.)

Answer (score 2):

This question cannot be answered using physical principles.  Also, there are so many possible variations on this type of question that it cannot be answered without additional details.

I do not want to pass judgment on something I do not know in this specific case, but whenever students ask me a question like this, they want to be told how to choose a particular equation to solve a problem based on the format of the question, but show limited interest in understanding the methodology behind the solution.

If this is not your case, maybe you can provide an example of a specific question and identify what *conceptually* confuses you in this example?

Answer (score 1):

> *Why must this question stay closed?*

Well it's not anymore, but it *should* be closed. There are several problems that I see with it:

1. **Too broad**: as there are several different types of parabolic trajectory problems (e.g., flat level, elevated origin, elevated end point, ranges, max heights, length, etc) and even more kinematic problems, what you're asking for is essentially a list of methods that could be used to solve a problem.
2. **Unclear**: you could be asking for a specific problem, but since you've not identified it, it's hard to say.
3. **Homework-like**: the method by which you solve a problem is *not* a concept and we routinely close questions asking "how do I solve this" given our long-standing [policy on the matter](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301).

To me, I would think that #3 is most strong reason for closure, but #1 is probably not too far behind; #2 is then the weakest reason for closure, but would still be valid in my books.

Comment: "the method by which you solve a problem is not a concept" how is this at all generally true under any reasonable definition of concept?

Comment: and what is the benefit to *anyone* to close a question that already has an accepted answer?

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber Concepts tend to be *why* questions, rather than *how* questions. Hence, asking "How do I do X" is not a concept while "Why is X the case?" is a concept. Answers, accepted or not, have absolutely no bearing on whether a *question* is on topic.

Comment: There is no definition of concept that I can find that supports your definition of concept. I was unaware stack exchange had an independent notion of the word concept that we were all supposed to be aware of somehow. I was also told by a professor which I highly agree with that "why" questions cannot be answer in physics. Physics literally was invented to solve "how" questions.

Comment: I believe [this definition of Concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept) is in line with what everyone here believes the word means and how we use it regularly. And your professor is specifying a distinction of [the philosopher's "why" vs scientist's "how"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90164/25301). That does not at all mean that physics questions cannot answer a question leading with why.

Comment: I think this might be clearer if we look at [conceptual questions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_question).  The idea of a "concept" is a bit vague, but a "conceptual question" pretty clear in what the difference is.

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand why the question should be closed. In particular, the question is

1. **Not too broad:** Every single kinematics problem is the same. If you cannot see this, then I'm not sure you've ever done kinematics problems.
2. **Not unclear:** See point 1.
3. **Not homework-like:** The way that one understands and does a kinematics problem is certainly based in concepts. Splitting motion into orthogonal components is a *concept*. $N$ first order differential equations requiring $N$ initial conditions to be specified is a *concept*.

Comment: Item 1 neglects projectile motion problems, which seemed to be the main focus of OP. Item 3 is obviously false, as we define homework-like questions as those by which the method of solving a problem is the focus. OP is literally asking for the method by which a subset of problems can be solved $\equiv$ homework.

Comment: The statement that asking about methods cannot be equal to asking about concepts is obviously false under any reasonable definition of "concept". Despite me saying this 5x to different reputable users, nobody has been able to provide a response or explanation for why this equality (for which the entire homework policy rests upon) is be true. @KyleKanos